# How to install or use python lib in python 3 instead 2?

Tags: software-installation, python, python3

I insatlled matplotlib using followig command :

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

And after that I run a sample matplotlib program using python abc.py. It works well.
But when I run it in python3 abc.py. It gives missing module errors.
I don't know how to this install work?
Help me with this problem.

PS : I don't want to use python2.7 anymore. So any suggestion with removing or replacing python3 with python2 will be good.

Comment: Don't remove Python 2; your system needs it even if you don't want to use `matplotlib` in Python 2.

Comment: The answers to the linked question include instructions to install Matplotlib for Python 3. I'm voting to keep this question closed as a duplicate.